# Star rank in table row are displayed outside the table

Tags: java, sql, codenameone

when I Run the project the table rows are displayed correctly except the rank stars the show outside the table and inside the colonne a text appears as displayed in the image :
[image]

```
public ListTasksForm(Form previous) {
    SpanLabel sp = new SpanLabel();
    sp.setText(ServiceTask.getInstance().getAllArticles().toString());
    ArrayList<Articles> articles = ServiceTask.getInstance().getAllArticles();
    Object[][] rows = new Object[articles.size()][];
    for (int iter = 0; iter < rows.length; iter++) {
        rows[iter] = new Object[]{
            articles.get(iter).getName(), articles.get(iter).getDescription(), articles.get(iter).getLabel(), articles.get(iter).getQuantity(),
            articles.get(iter).getRating(), add(createStarRankSlider(articles.get(iter).getId_article()))
        };

    }
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"name", "description", "label", "quantity", "rating", "rate"}, rows);
            Table table = new Table(model);
            add(table);
            getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToLeftBar("", FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_BACK, e -> previous.showBack());
        }
    });
```

and this is the function for the star rank creation

```
private Slider createStarRankSlider(int id) {
Slider starRank = new Slider();
starRank.setEditable(true);
starRank.setMinValue(0);
starRank.setMaxValue(10);
int fontSize = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(3);
Font fnt = Font.createTrueTypeFont("Handlee", "Handlee-Regular.ttf").
        derive(fontSize, Font.STYLE_PLAIN);
Style s = new Style(0xffff33, 0, fnt, (byte) 0);
Image fullStar = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_STAR, s).toImage();
s.setOpacity(100);
s.setFgColor(0);
Image emptyStar = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_STAR, s).toImage();
initStarRankStyle(starRank.getSliderEmptySelectedStyle(), emptyStar);
initStarRankStyle(starRank.getSliderEmptyUnselectedStyle(), emptyStar);
initStarRankStyle(starRank.getSliderFullSelectedStyle(), fullStar);
initStarRankStyle(starRank.getSliderFullUnselectedStyle(), fullStar);
starRank.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fullStar.getWidth() * 5, fullStar.getHeight()));
starRank.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        ServiceTask.getInstance().UpdateRank(id,starRank.getIncrements());

    }
});

return starRank;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the code for the `initStarRankStyle` but it's pretty obvious what you did here. You just relied on the behavior of the container. `Table` derives `Container` so it includes all of its methods e.g. `add(Component)`.

But these methods won't work correctly since a table fetches its data from the model and invokes `add` internally. So you're logic is conflicting with the table.

You need to derive table and define how you want that data to be rendered. You can do that by overriding the method `protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable)` as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/understanding-the-table-component.html).

Comment: Can u explain what do u mean by "You need to derive table and define how you want that data to be rendered" how do i use the method createCell to the rate stars exactly ?

Comment: This is an MVC component. The table model tells you how many stars should be drawn, right? The Table is the view. So if the value in the model changes the table implicitly creates the component for the given cell. If you want to use a custom component in the table you need to use it as explained in the article I linked above.

Comment: Can u give me an example :

Comment: for example a code of creating a table with and Evaluate button on each row please ?

Comment: There's a full example in the link at the bottom of my answer